# what catalyst to use for the reaction between AgNO3 and NaCl?

Tags: acid-base, experimental-chemistry, transition-metals, catalysis

What is the best catalyst to use for the reaction between AgNO3 and NaCl that would result in a change in activation of energy so therefore more precipitate formed. Please give me the ways I can catalyze this reaction with the methodology on how can I carry it out. please be more specific.

Comment: This is not a reaction that needs a catalyst.

Comment: No catalyst is needed for this reaction.

Comment: Probably not but I want to try a catalyst and see if there will be a difference.

Comment: Even if there was a catalyst, it would not affect the amount of precipitate, as catalysts do not affect equilibrium.

Answer (score 3):

The reaction of chloride ion with silver ion is 1:1 and highly *quantitative*. It is one of the best studied reactions inorganic chemistry. You cannot carry this reaction in basic/alkaline medium by any means. There is no need of any catalyst. This was worked out at least 120 years ago by people who were interested in atomic weight determinations. Theodore Richard got Nobel prize on this subject.

Comment: I upvoted, as this is a great answer! I still suspect this is, however, just a camouflage question to extract a 'solution' to a prior inappropriate question.

Comment: No need to be paranoid. There are plenty of useless and potentially dangerous questions here posted from all over the world. We don't need to play Sherlock Holmes.

Comment: I apologize for the paranoia, as I thought I am seeing either a curious innocent non-chemist wanting to learn chemistry by starting with the synthesis to a high explosive, or someone not at all innocent persistently trying to do the same thing, either scenario likely does not end well, in my assessment.

Comment: so by what you mean by the answer is that no other variable could increase the amount of precipitate between Ag and Cl except for concentration?

Comment: No variable can increase the amount of precipitate. It is 1:1. For each mol Cl,  1 mol AgCl is precipitated.

Comment: I appreciate your valuable comment and everyone else comment that tried to help.